# The same C# code produces different output in Visio Professional and Premium

Tags: visio

I have built a simple conversion Add In, but its behavior is unfortunately different with the different Visio Editions (Visio 2010 Professional and Visio 2010 Premium).
The Add In takes a Process-Diagram created with Shapes from Stencil_1.vss and creates a new slightly different Process-Diagram with Shapes from Stencil_2.vsd. It loops through a Visio page and for each shape founded creates a new shapes from new master shape (from Stencil_2.vsd) and drop it into the new page. Geometry, captions etc. are the same, only the shape-appearance is changed. Below is the source diagram:

[image: the source diagram]

When I run the code into Visio 2010 Professional the swimlane shapes are drawn correctly.

[image: run from Visio 2010 Prof]

When I run the same code from Visio Premium the swimlane appearance and layout are mismatched:
[image: run from Visio 2010 Premium]

Both times i drop the SAME Shape("Swimlane" from the same stencil) into the Page with the SAME Code fragment:

```
Visio.Master vm = swimlane_stencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Swimlane");
Visio.Shape TargetShape = targetPage.Drop(vm, shape_x, shape_y);
```

How could I ensure, that the code produces any time the same (correct) output? Must I disable any (premium)features in the swimlane-shapesheet?

Answer (score 1):

The cross-functional flowchart shapes are backed by an addon so that shapes get correctly positioned within swimlanes and the page etc.  Most shapes have an on drop event that calls out to the addon for their respective functionality.

By the looks of it the addon isn't being invoked correctly in your Visio Premium instance.  For example, there's a function in the [EventDrop cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769082.aspx):

=RUNADDONWARGS("CFF14","/cmd=20001")

..where CFF14 is the 2010 version of the cross-functional flowchart addon.

Bear in mind that 2010 also uses [container shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff959245.aspx) within the cross-functional flowchart solution.  Are you using the correct 2010 'target' shapes?

There should be no difference in functionality, as far as the cross-functional flowchart is concerned, between Professional and Premium editions as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time!

> Bear in mind that 2010 also uses container shapes within the
>   cross-functional flowchart solution. Are you using the correct 2010
>   'target' shapes?

The ‘target’ shapes in both cases are the Swimlanes from the cross functional flowchart stencil.

I tested the same Add In-code on another "Professional"-Machine, it was successful, I mean the "Swimlane" shapes are positioned correct and without separators and Title-section. 
I also uninstall and install again the Premium instance and nothing is changed, the same code produces the same diagram drawn above. Swimlanes PinX are changed and separators and title-section are added.

- I noticed, that in the “wrong diagrams” only the first dropped
  Swimlane shape is correct
- The  following(later dropped) Swimlanes are wrong positioned and separators and title-bar are added. They have:
  User.msvShapeCategories="**CFF Container**;DoNotContain", the right Swimlane-shapes have: User.msvShapeCategories="**Swimlane**;DoNotContain"
- Also I noticed, that the wrong Swimlanes are derived
  from xfunc_m.vss ( User.visMasterStencil = "**xfunc_m.vss**")
- I remove the value “xfunc_m.vss” from the User.visMasterStencil Cell
  and update the stencil

Now it works fine, I hope this explanation is useful for others and somebody could explain this behavior better than me :)